# I want to use my own domain email but in gmail is it possible?

Tags: email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Outsource my email server to Google](https://serverfault.com/questions/18645/outsource-my-email-server-to-google)

I want to use my own domain email `me@mydomain.com` but in gmail is it possible?

I just want to use my own email address but with gmail interface.

just for my email. a single person's email.

Answer (score 4):

[Google Apps Standard](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/group/) will do exactly what you want

Sign up the domain. Setup the proper DNS records. Activate email. You're good to go.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to use my own domain email
>   me@mydomain.com but in gmail is it
>   possible?

[Yes](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/group/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

yes if you have a fully qualified mailbox its possible to do it. Go under "Settings" then "Fowarding and POP/IMAP" to setup your mail

Comment: What exactly is a "fully qualified mailbox"?

Comment: fully qualified mailbox = a mail account where u can use a normal pop client like thunderbird to get your mails